# How can I install Mediawiki extensions from the command line?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-installation

I'm trying to automate Wikimedia installation using Ansible and the Wikimedia [command-line install script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Install.php).

I noticed the current version includes script parameters for installing extensions. From the script help command:

```
$ php maintenance/install.php --help

CLI-based MediaWiki installation and configuration.
Default options are indicated in parentheses.

Usage: php install.php [--conf|--confpath|--dbgroupdefault|--dbname|--dbpass|--dbpassfile|--dbpath|--dbport|--dbprefix|-
-dbschema|--dbserver|--dbtype|--dbuser|--env-checks|--extensions|--globals|--help|--installdbpass|--installdbuser|--lang
|--memory-limit|--mwdebug|--pass|--passfile|--profiler|--quiet|--scriptpath|--server|--skins|--wiki|--with-extensions] [
name] <admin>

...

Script specific parameters:
    --extensions: Comma-separated list of extensions to install
    --with-extensions: Detect and include extensions
```

However, I am unable to find any other information on how best to use these parameters. Neither the Wikimedia manual pages on the install.php script or Extensions documents them:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Install.php
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extensions

Can someone point me to more details documentation on these parameters or provide an example of how to use them?

I am planning to do some trial and error and will answer this question myself if I figure out how they work before anyone else answers. But I know extension installation can get complicated and usually involves making config file updates so I hope I could find some existing documentation to guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answer

These extension parameters simply add a line to the `LocalSettings.php` file, if the named extension is found in the `extensions` directory, to load the extension at runtime.

#### Long Answer

I played with this a little. I tested the `--with-extensions` which, per the help docs, will `detect and include extensions`. What this appears to mean is that it will scan the extensions directory and install any extensions it find there.

I ran the following command:

```
php maintenance/install.php --with-extensions --dbserver="localhost" --dbname=foo --dbuser=foo --dbpass=foo --server="https://wiki.foo.localhost" --script path=/mediawiki -en --pass=foo "My Wiki Name" "Admin"
```

It produced the following block in my `LocalSettings.php` config file listing the default packages included with the current version of the Mediawiki core:

```
# Enabled extensions. Most of the extensions are enabled by adding
# wfLoadExtensions('ExtensionName');
# to LocalSettings.php. Check specific extension documentation for more details.
# The following extensions were automatically enabled:
wfLoadExtension( 'CategoryTree' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CiteThisPage' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CodeEditor' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ConfirmEdit' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Gadgets' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ImageMap' );
wfLoadExtension( 'InputBox' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Interwiki' );
wfLoadExtension( 'LocalisationUpdate' );
wfLoadExtension( 'MultimediaViewer' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Nuke' );
wfLoadExtension( 'OATHAuth' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ParserFunctions' );
wfLoadExtension( 'PdfHandler' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Poem' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Renameuser' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ReplaceText' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SpamBlacklist' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
wfLoadExtension( 'TitleBlacklist' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );
```

The complexity of this parameter, probably wisely, goes no further than that.

I tried running this command to see if the `--extensions=GoogleLogin` parameter would auto-magically install the [GoogleLogin extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GoogleLogin). It did not. Rather it reported this error:

```
Could not find the registration file for the extension "GoogleLogin"
```

So if you're looking for a more full-featured Composer-like extension package-manager, this is not it.

When I downloaded the GoogleLogin extension and placed it in the `extensions` directory and ran the `--with-extensions` parameter and it did include it in the config file extensions block.

Without explicitly testing it, I concluded the `--extensions` parameters operates the same way as `--with-extensions` except that it will rewrite to the `LocalSettings.php` config file only those extensions explicitly specified *and* found in the `extensions` directory.